# Can't figure out how to send HTTP POST request from a JSP- with username/password

Tags: java, jsp, http, authentication, http-post

I've been banging my head against this one all week and I'm finally one step away from a working POC. Any help with this is appreciated, and hope y'all are having a happy Friday regardless.

My goal is to create a JSP that will:

-Send a predetermined, hardcoded username/password to a Guidewire Servlet via HTTP POST

-At which point the servlet authenticates, logs the user in, and redirects them to the trainingApp login page

-Without any user input, just run it and you'll land on Guidewire already logged in.

I've got it working! However, it's not up to spec. One of my requirements is that the JSP does all of this automatically on run. It's meant to send the same username/password combo every time, with no need for user input.

I've only been able to get the JSP to work as a username/password form with a 'submit' button. like this:

```
<body>

<%@page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@page import="java.net.*" %>

    <form method="post" action="http://localhost:8180/pc/service/test">
        User:<input name="username"/>
        Password:<input name="password"/>
        <input type="Submit" value="Log in"/>
    </form>

  </body> 
</html>
```

This sends the username/password, sure enough, but I need something more like this, and try as I might I can't get it to work.

```
<% 
URLConnection connection = new URL("http://localhost:8180/pc/service/test").openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true); // Triggers POST.
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic c3U6Z3c=");
%>
```

I can't seem to get the POST request to fire off and send the auth data without a "submit" button or a form to pass in the username and password. The servlet seems to be working fine, and I'm relieved to be almost done.

Thanks in advance if you can help!

Comment: You could try adding JavaScript to automatically submit the page when the page is loaded in the browser.  However, this will expose what sounds like a shared/generic user ID/password.  Do you trust all the users?

Comment: This is meant to be a proof-of-concept, not for use by actual users just yet. I'm going to try and figure out how to do business in Javascript because nothing else is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

I'm still using the form, HOWEVER:

the inputs are now hidden AND, here's the key:
I added an onload tag to the body to submit the form on page load!

WORKING AS INTENDED.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the implicit object in JSP, i.e. request.

```
String name = request.getParameter("username");
```

Using the name, we can redirect to the form or to the specified URL.

Comment: Could you be more specific about how I could implement this? I'm able to redirect to the servlet but I can't for the life of me get the request to pass the auth data as a header when I do so. it just never makes it to the servlet.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need a form. just do a redirect and pass the authorization header.

You can do a digest as well, which could be more secure if this url isn't https

String headerKey = "Authorization";

String headerValue = "Basic + Base64.encodeString(user+":"+pass);

response.setHeader(headerKey ,headerValue);

String redirectURL = "http://whatever.com/myJSPFile.jsp";

response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);

Comment: I'm not able to send the auth data with this method. I tried:
`<%
String headerKey = "Authorization";
String headerValue = "Basic c3U6Z3c=" ;
response.setHeader(headerKey,headerValue);
String redirectURL = "http://localhost:8180/pc/service/test";
response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
%>`

I've got the servlet logging the headers of any incoming request and the request sent this way did not contain an auth header. What might I be doing wrong?